# What is the pseudocode for parsing using functional or procedural paradigms instead of object oriented?

Tags: swift, oop, stream, functional-programming, nsxmlparser

Here is the background. I am currently learning Swift and I am currently exploring its NSXMLParser class. Given I am still trying to understand the object oriented thought process, my main query is to understand why multiple objects have to interact when parsing given the program is only a few lines of code. Additionally, how would we parse XML data from websites using streams or another paradigm such as functional or procedural? (I started programming by using LISP.)

Comment: Is there any chance you could narrow your question down and/or give some example code to make it clearer what you are asking?  I've found parsing to be trickier in FP but there are typically libraries to help with it.

Comment: Yes, after rereading my question I realize that I need to be more concise: So my question is, how would a functional programmer go about the business of parsing XML data? After doing a little more research on parsing I realize that this can be a complex topic.

Comment: I found an answer to my question. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185879/writing-a-formal-language-parser-with-lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185879/writing-a-formal-language-parser-with-lisp)

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution!  I'm going to suggest this be closed/on-hold with a link to that question as a duplicate.  No hard feelings, of course.  This will help others be directed to that answer more easily.